# Can we add UILabel to splash screen in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Can we add an view to the splash screen in iphone?. I have a default.png file in my resources directory but when the splash screen pops up i want to display an text on the splash screen image is it possible in code.

Answer (score 3):

No. [Unless you apply some symlink tricks (only possible for 2.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959080/dynamic-default-png-splashscreen-in-3-0-iphone-sdk), `Default.png` cannot be changed.

And the `Default.png` is displayed by SpringBoard before your app's code starts to run, so this is impossible.

You can construct a customized splash screen in your `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` though.