# Multiple default.png files in an app

Tags: iphone

Some native iPhone applications (like Clock) display different default images while loading depending on where the user was when the app shut down last.

I wonder if that's something only Apple apps can do, or if mortals can do that, too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic (Default.png) splashscreen in 3.0 \[iPhone SDK\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959080/dynamic-default-png-splashscreen-in-3-0-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it's for immortals only. There is however one for each orientation and a separate set for the iPad. But nothing that allows you to change those once built.

Answer (score 2):

Use a blank Default.png and then in your app delegate's `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method, load a `UIView` that contains your dynamic content. This solution sidesteps any conflicts with Apple's SDK terms as well as all technical problems.

Comment: Isn't DidFinishLaunching kind of moot? By the time I get there I can display the actual UI I want, not a static PNG.

Comment: Not at all. If your app loads quickly, you can simulate a splash screen here, or any other custom load screen.