# Can an iphone app change its home screen icon and name after installation?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

Can an iphone app change its home screen icon and name after installation?

What i want to do is make a generic application for several of our clients, that upon installation and login by users it detects which of our client it applies to and changes its icon and name to reflect the appropriate branding.

Is this going to be possible? Or are we simply going to have to make (and submit for approval...) one app per client?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Updated**: since iOS 10 it's possible to change the application icon from the list of pre-defined ones in the Info.plist. However display name still stays the constant.

**Outdated:** Since app's name is in Info.plist which resides with app's icon in app's bundle (which is readonly) - it cannot. You can only change your app's name and icon after releasing an update into the appstore. You may though change application icon's badge value. But as I see in your scenario - it won't fit your needs at all.

Comment: What about with something like this? http://collison.ie/blog/2008/11/dynamic-defaultpng-files-on-the-iphone

Comment: Looks like it was only possible in ios 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959080/dynamic-default-png-splashscreen-in-3-0-iphone-sdk