# How to change the iOS app display name programmatically in React native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

Actually, I want to change the App Icon and App display name dynamically in my iOS and Android **React Native** app. Here, I can change only the app icon in iOS and the app icon and app display name in Android by [react-native-change-icon](https://github.com/skb1129/react-native-change-icon). Now I am facing problem in changing th e app name dynamically. Is there any way to change the App display name from React-Native for iOS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[As stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255922/can-an-iphone-app-change-its-home-screen-icon-and-name-after-installation) it is not possible to change the display name of a native app dynamically. This would be the same case for react-native apps.

Comment: You should not refer to a Post which is more than 10 years old if there are no updated answers.