# Can we change product name / default image of application dynamically?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

Is it possible to change the `Product name`/ `default image` (Splash - screen) of application dynamically from code..

Comment: This link will helps you...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788454/iphone-showing-dynamic-splash-screens

Comment: No. iOS does not allow 3rd party apps to change the name under the icon nor change the Default.png at runtime. Only Apple apps can do this.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Its providing splash screen with adding image view in appdidfinsh launching method. That's i know & it will provide blank screen for splash screen. till now i have done same, but i am looking is this possible or not..?

Answer (score 0):

Product Name :
I'm not sure if you can do that. Apple won't allow it. Once the app is uploaded you can't change the Product Name.

Splash screen :
Here you can do little manipulation. Like, keep your app launching view controller as just one `UIImageView`. Show it for few seconds and push user to your first screen. And you can achieve the effect of Splash Screen.

Comment: I Know about that, time being integrated till now same. Thanks for the reply.