# Xcode iOS app loading screen

Tags: xcode, animation, loading, default

Looking to do two things where the normal 'default.png' image loads in an iOS app.

For example, like how the 'cut the rope' app starts up.

1) want to display two logo screens on starting (well one logo screen and one loading screen)

2) want to have the second screen animate a 'loading' bar that shows the app loading

Having a lot of difficulty in finding any good examples or tutorials on either!

Anyone got any links or helpful ideas on either of these items?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the default and the initial screen to be the same?  Or are you looking for help creating the loading bar?

Comment: It's really that second 'loading' screen that I am looking at how to do. Easy to create a first default.png logo, but then want the display to go from that static image to a screen with a 'loading' image that displays while the rest of the app finishes loading.

Comment: Make your initial view controller that loading screen, instantiate an NSTimer that pings a method that checks to see if it's finished loading and advances your loading bar if it's not.  When it's done, change the BOOL to YES and push your first viewController.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know of any good examples or tutorials of this? Also, I will be using storyboarding in Xcode to build this app in case that makes any difference.

Comment: Just add a viewController in the storyboard, set it to your new class, and make sure you check "is Initial ViewController".  Out of curiosity, are you loading a URL or parsing a file?  Set up that initial viewController and play around a bit.  This question is too big and open-ended for a coherent response.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had made that clear in the initial question. This isn't to show loading or parsing of a file - it is to show loading of the actual app itself. The main app will have several pages, graphics, screens, etc, and we want this to be an initial loading bar before the main app finished loading and starts. That's why I wasn't sure about using an initial view controller - because doesn't that then only start showing and animation once the actual app has loaded?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959080/dynamic-default-png-splashscreen-in-3-0-iphone-sdk