# iOS Animated Splash Screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, splash-screen, dynamic-splash-screen

Is it possible to add an .fla file as splash screen in iOS development? If not what are the other formats of animated files does a splash screen accept? Does it accept animated gifs? or .swf files? or do i have to write the animation frame by frame.

If so what is the procedure? Do i have to add it the same way i add an image just have the extension differ?

I have an .fla file that i would like to add to my code. Unfortunately i couldn't find any material on whether this is feasible or not.

Answer (score 37):

Seems like people here doesn't know the difference between splash screen and launch image.
Launch images are static, you configure them with xcode and you can't change them.

But in a splash screen you can do whatever you like, it's just a viewController where you show an animation, a video, or any other thing.
You show the splass screen after the launch image and before your "landing page".
Then, in a splash screen you can create an animation frame by frame, or load a .mp4 video in a `MPMoviePlayerController` as Krumelur said.

People using animated splash screens, usually use a launch image with the color of the splash screen (color of the first animation frame or the color of the video), so it seems that the launch image is part of the splass screen.

Answer (score 9):

It is relatively easy to create an animated splash screen. You need to create a compliant .mp4 file on and use the first frame of this movie as the launch image. Then instantiate a `MPMoviePlayerController` on app launch to play the movie in full screen. The movie will start a few moments after the launch image has been shown.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like possible. You may want to have a look of following post 
[dynamic splash screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959080/dynamic-default-png-splashscreen-in-3-0-iphone-sdk)

You have to write the animation frame by frame.

Another guide for animating splash screen [Animation on splash screen](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2134)

Hence you will have to show splash screen and then you may add any animation on view or add any movie(for example: .mov)

Hope this will help!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display .fla files on iOS. Flash is not allowed as content in iOS.
Also, splash screens can only be static graphics.

Answer (score 0):

An iOS splash screen is static. So it's just an image.
But you can add your splashscreen and then just add a movie (.mov or other Apple format) just after your splashscreen disappears.