# how to add .gif in splash screen in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Is it possible to add an `.gif file` as splash screen in iOS app?
How to create dynamic splash screens? Any idea how to add gif in splash screen

Comment: you can use SDImageCache for that

Comment: @Birendra SDImageCache for using an animation in a splash screen? :/ How come?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Animated Splash Screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913444/ios-animated-splash-screen)

Comment: [imgViewVid sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[arrVideo valueForKey:@"photo_path"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage sd_animatedGIFNamed:@"loading1"]];

Comment: @Birendra Yes and where are you going to call that code in Launch screen? And why use that extension? You can start animation with UIImageView itself.

Comment: you have create a class and then give it this name to lanch screen storyboar

Answer (score 0):

You have to view controller like splash screen which stay for 3-4 second. Launch image gif not possible.

1) You can do it by playing sequence of images one by one. There is method available in UIImageView class to play image array.

2) You can play video of 5 sec.

**EDIT**

```
NSArray *animationArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpg"],
                                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"images1.jpg"],
                                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"images5.jpg"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"index3.jpg"],
                        nil];
    UIImageView *animationView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 460)];
        animationView.backgroundColor=[UIColor purpleColor];
        animationView.animationImages=animationArray;
        animationView.animationDuration=1.5;
    animationView.animationRepeatCount=0;
        [animationView startAnimating]; 
        [self.view addSubview:animationView];
```

Comment: Best way is to play video of 3-4 sec and once video play complete move to next view controller. So you have to play video inside your rootview controller.

Comment: i try same code but first show white splash screen then show animation

Comment: Have you set launch image?

Comment: is it posible to appdelget.m file. add self.window

Comment: I am not getting you. what you are trying to say?

Comment: not set image in launch image becuse i am use .gif image

Comment: You have to set otherwise white screen is always there.

Comment: You must have to set launch image as it's apple guideline.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you:

```
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSInteger animationImageCount = 38;
for (int i = 0; i &lt; animationImageCount; i++) {
    // Images are numbered IndexedImagesInMyAnimation0, 1, 2, etc...
    [images addObject:(id)[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"IndexedImagesInMyAnimation%d", i]].CGImage];
}

CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationDiscrete;
animation.duration = animationImageCount / 24.0; // 24 frames per second
animation.values = images;
animation.repeatCount = 1;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
[self.animationImageView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"];
```

Also as you know the repeatCount and duration of single cycle animation, you can easily calculate total animation time like this:

totalAnimationTime = repeatCount * duration

Now, you can use this totalAnimationTime in a timer and switch your view controller.

Comment: i am try it same code but frist show white splash screen then show animation

Comment: I believe you have images locally.  If yes then, you can use the first image as default image in UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

According to apple's guideline it is not possible to use `gif` as splash screen or launch image.

If you are using story board for launch screen (> ios 7) then you can use `jpg` but below or equal version to ios 7, you have only option is `png`.

You can achieve animation kind of startup by making your first view controller animated and make it work as splash scree. In this case you should not set any splash image of launch screen storyboard(or set black background color), so it will show black screen for a second when app will be launching and then your first view controller will be animate and your app will got startup with animation or `gif`.

Hope this will help :)